# Session not created exception when starting chromedriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting some weird behaviour when using selenium chrome: When the tests start chrome, if there is no chrome instance running, chrome starts normally.
If there is already a chrome instance running, a new tab starts in that chrome window, and after a while the following message is thrown:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 60.000)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

This is also the case for parallel testing. One instance is started and the other tests, are trying to start on a new tab, and fail with same message as above.
I am using `Java 17`, `selenium 4.17.0`, `chrome 121.0.6167.161`, and `chromedriver 121.0.6167.85`. Chromedriver and rest of drivers, are installed automatically through `webdrivermanager 5.6.3` and `testNG 7.7.1`
Noting also that all edge driver and firefox are working perfectly.
Finally, I have tried several of the proposed ideas in regards to chrome options, but still no luck.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried in `headless` mode ?

Comment: Yes, but this is not the solution that I am looking for

Comment: Have you tried using a keyboard shortcut to open a new window? Could work whether or not a browser is already open, though it would sometimes add one extra window.

Comment: This is another "hack", like headless, that is not practical, nor cures the initial problem described.a new Chromedriver() instance should have a specific behavior.

Comment: are you setting the driver to use a specific profile?

Comment: @browsermator : nope.not using any profile setting on chrome options

Comment: "If there is already a chrome instance running, a new tab starts in that chrome window" - this confuses me a bit, as by default, despite you have already any instance of chrome open, new test run should open a new window, not a tab. If you really have a default setup and do not have any specific case that is not mentioned here I would say for chrome in general it does not work as expected. It has to be a new window. Maybe if you can add more code how you start browser, what options - may be helpful.

Comment: Exactly, that why i am a bit troubled on what is going on. Chrome driver instances spawn new chrome windows and they are independent of it you have a window already opened in the background. Let alone that this happens only on my windows machine. same code works as expected on linux..

Comment: the only thing I can think of is that the existing browser is launched by an IDE, and you have set the debugger port to same in your driver options.  You should include your driver initialization code.

Answer (score -1):

Hi @gandalf_the_cool,

this is very common problem while working with Selenium.

This sessionNotCreated error and response code 500 comes when your selenium code is trying to access real browser and trying to execute the command but it is not able to find any real browser. the probable reasons are -

1. you don't have chromedriver.exe in your system or the path to .exe file is not correct.
2. if you have chromedriver.exe then it is not compatible with your current chrome browser in your machine. so just upgrade your chrome browser version or the chromedriver.exe.

my recommendation is that currently in latest version of selenium you do not have to provide any chromedriver.exe binary/ path. just use selenium maven dependency to create new chromeDriver/ edgeDriver as per your requirement. It will download required .exe file in ~/.cache/selenium

just use selenium dependency, not to use anything else.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version> </version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: I am not doing any manual setting of path or something. This happens both with Selenium Manager and with WebDriver Manager, as stated in the description.
And also if a version incompatibility was in place, it wouldn't work when specific circumstances were there (also in initial description), but it wouldn't work at all.